# Airflow DAG missing runs in hourly schedule

Tags: airflow

I'm running into a rather bizarre issue of an airflow hourly Dag missing a scheduled run every day.

This hourly dag is schedule for 0 * * * *, yet it does not generate a run for 0500 hours

[image]

I have another daily Dag that has a crossdag dependency to a task in that hourly dag. The daily dag is schedule for 0 5 * * *

I don't know what could cause Airflow to skip scheduling an entire run. My dags don't have any settings for concurrency or max_active_runs. Don't have task level concurrency limits either (pool, task_concurrency). Even if they are set, I believe these parameters would only queue the execution of dags or tasks, not skipping a schedule run entirely(maybe someone confirm)?

I'm guessing it would be something in the global Airflow settings that limits the number of active dag runs being scheduled at the same time. Any suggestion what it might be? The environment has been set up by our infrastructure team a long time ago so I would need to provide some instructions for them to take a look

Airflow version 1.10.12

Comment: I assume you have `catchup=False` in your DAG? If so - that may be the source for the trouble.

Comment: @Elad Can you elaborate on this? I do have catchup set to False so only the new runs get scheduled, but my dag has been turned on for a couple of days and it still keeps on skipping the 0500 hours run. Not sure what to do

Comment: mmm your comment make me suspect other issues as you claim it always skip specific run so there might be different issue. It's hard to comment without understanding the business logic of your DAG however if you don't want your DAG to skip runs you must set `catchup=True`. For example if the scheduler was down between 05:59 to 07:01 then the 05:00 execution run will not be fired. With `catchup=True` it's guaranteed that no matter what was the cause for a run to not start on schedule it will always handle the missing runs.

Comment: I don't think it's a scheduler downtime issue as I have other days that also execute at 0500 hours and they have the runs scheduled. I'll test out catch-up and see if I can get around this issue. Thanks